# Google ML KIT Vision Face Detection and face filters

Tags: android, google-mlkit

Does any one know what kind of technology used in face detection in google ml kit vision and what kind of methods use in face detection https://towardsdatascience.com/face-detection-for-beginners-e58e8f21aad9

Answer (score 1):

ML Kit Vision Face Detection uses the "Appearance-Based method -- 4.3.Neural-Networks" method.

Comment: haii , thanks for the answer but do have any reference, even in google official sites they don't mention the technology for ml kit vision face detection

Comment: We do not usually go to that level of implementation details, but I'm providing an answer here, since you asked.

Answer (score 0):

in android, we use vision dependency to detect face or text from images or cameras. In this way, if we want to compare images then we use comparison methods and logic. if you are interesting you can search *OCR* this topic will help you to learn and acknowledge your question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).